# Every homotopy class contains at least a harmonic representative

Tags: homotopy-theory, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory, harmonic-functions

Let $(M^3,g)$ be a closed, connected and oriented Riemannian $3$-manifold. A circle-valued map $v : M \to S^1$ is harmonic iff the gradient $1$-form $\omega_v = v^* d\theta \in \Omega_1(M)$ is harmonic in the Hodge sense: $d \omega_v = 0$ and $\delta \omega_v = 0$. It can be seen that this happens precisely when $v$ minimizes the Dirichlet energy in its homotopy class $[v] \in [M:S^1]$. Thus, by Hodge theory, each homotopy class of a circle-valued map contains a harmonic representative.

**My question** is whether every homotopy class of $S^2$-valued maps contains a harmonic representative. More precisely: given $u : M \to S^2$ a smooth map, does there exist a harmonic map $u_0 : M \to S^2$ such that $u$ is smooth and homotopic to $u$?

**A parallel question**: if $u_0 : M \to S^2$ is any harmonic map, can we say that $u_0^* \sigma \in \Omega_2(M)$ is a harmonic $2$-form, where $\sigma$ is the area form of (the round) $S^2$?

Comment: No, the theory for targets with some positive curvature is very complicated.  For example, there is no harmonic map from the 2-torus to the 2-sphere of degree 1 (for any choice of metrics).

Answer (score 4):

As Andy says, the answer is 'no':  It is known that there is no harmonic map of degree $1$ from the torus to the $2$-sphere.  I forget who first observed this. (**Amended after Andy's comment:** It's originally due to J. C. Wood in the early 1970s, see Andy's comment for the exact reference.)

If I have time, I can put in the argument, but the essential outline of the argument is this:

There are two kinds of harmonic maps from the torus to the $2$-sphere.  Those that are conformal and those that are not.

If it is conformal, then, up to reversing the orientation on the torus, it is a holomorphic map, and it is well-known that a non-constant holomorphic map from the torus to the $2$-sphere has  degree at least 2.  (In fact, there is such a holomorphic map of any degree $d\ge 2$.)

If it is not conformal, then a simple calculation shows that the degree of the mapping is zero.  (Essentially, one produces an explicit $1$-form on the torus whose differential is the pullback of the area form on the $2$-sphere.)

Thus, there is no harmonic map of degree 1 from the torus to the $2$-sphere.

Comment: I think the result goes back to Wood, a discussion can be found here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82593933.pdf.

Comment: @AndySanders:  Thanks for the reference!  I knew it had been known a long time, but I had forgot where I learned it.

Comment: What does this imply for the case of dimension $3$?

Comment: @EduardoLonga:  Do you mean dimension 3 for the range or the domain, or both?

Comment: The domain of dimension $3$ and the codomain being the round $2$-sphere.

Comment: @EduardoLonga:  I don't know an example off the top of my head, but I suspect that existence of a harmonic mapping in a given homotopy class of maps $f:M^3\to S^2$ fails in many cases, just because the regularity theory for a nonlinear PDE gets harder as the dimension of the domain goes up.  Maybe Andy knows something more specific about this.  A good place to start is the work of Schoen and Uhlenbeck on regularity of harmonic maps.